# How to get android phone user's google account name?

Tags: android, google-account

So I am making mobile game with unity engine, think to release to android target.

Now my game will have my own custom highscore board, there I think when user earn score, game should send his identity nickname, score to server.

So for get his distinct name, I think to get his google account name. (of course I can choose option that receive user's input for his nickname, but well, tiresome)

I just only need email format's front part (i.e. username) 
**Example, if user's google account is asdf@gmail.com , I want to extract only "asdf".**

So, how to do it?

And is this good way for get his distinct nickname?

Thanks.

---

So I did like this, but does not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity implements        AndroidInterface{
private String usergoogleName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    GetUserName();      
} 
public void GetUserName(){
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    List<String> username = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        username.add(account.name);
    }
    usergoogleName = username.get(0);
    sendMessage("Main Camera", "JavaMsg", usergoogleName);
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(String target, String method, String params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(target, method, params);
}
```

and at unity side, I attached script to 'Main Camera' object and write,

```
public string name;
public void JavaMsg(string str){
    name = str;
}
void OnGUI(){
    GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 200, 300, 100), "google account name is " + name);
}
```

but when I run this at my phone after make .apk file, doesn't read account name.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using Google Play Games' api? https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Comment: @TristanWiley I can't use that, because my publisher doesn't allow 3rd party services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
List<String> username = new LinkedList<String>();

for (Account account : accounts) {
    username.add(account.name);
}
```

and add permission to android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Thanks, then can I use this code at unity and c# without any additional .dll or plugin files?

Comment: just chek it, http://hintdesk.com/android-use-accountmanager-with-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Thank for your link, but it is over range what I need. So write above code at android-unity plugin's java code, and when game start, send that username variable to unity and use it?

Comment: And what is here  'context'? AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);     I want to see full code.

Comment: in your activity can use 'this' instead of context

Comment: I did as above, GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 200, 300, 100), "google account name is " + name);  but after run .apk file, name is blank.

Comment: check account .Length

Comment: I revised code of unity side like, public void JavaMsg(string str){
  name = str;
  called = true;
 }
 bool called;
 void OnGUI(){
  GUI.Label(new Rect(100, 200, 500, 100), "google account name is " + name+"  and JavaMsg "+called);
 }

Comment: but 'called' remain false after run. So from java code, it doesn't call unity function.

Comment: ah never mind. I solved, I firstly mistaken input java plugin to other project. After I input .jar file from eclipse to right  unity project, and tested, it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string asdf@gmail.com and you want everything before the @ you can use .split();

```
String email = asdf@gmail.com
String[] parts = email.split("@");
String nickname = parts[0];
```