# Get username of the current profile

Tags: android

I have Motorola Moto G(4) running Android 7.0 . I want to build an app that just returns the current username. For example:

[image: Screenshot]

I just want the name 'Ankit' to return. How can this be done?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689855/5212133

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar I think the link you provided was for google account name. My question is different.