# How to access account name in android with API 26 or higher?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm developing an application, where I want to send the users account in an email. I've tried every example here in stackoverflow, also checked the Android Development site, but I couldn't retrieve any information using AccountManager. I've found the following information:

"In Android 8.0 (API level 26), apps can no longer get access to user accounts unless the authenticator owns the accounts or the user grants that access", but I still have no idea how to make get the account name.

Can anybody provide a working code snippet? It should work just with this:

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I'm developing for android wear.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372239/4698320

Comment: In settings -> Accounts: I find my google account, but this still returns an empty array

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689809/how-to-get-android-phone-users-google-account-name

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding on the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

That worked for me on API 27.