# How to get names of users and set text to TextView

Tags: android, list, android-permissions, google-account

Following this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689855/12205512) I created an app that shows the google account names of users of this app. 
But if I do in Android studio and I would like to set the text to display.

I must write:

```java
Textview context = findViewById(R.id.id_context);
context.setText((CharSequence) username);
```

Instead of:

```
System.out.println(username);
```

All code:

```java
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
List<String> username = new LinkedList<String>();

for (Account account : accounts) {
    username.add(account.name);
}

TextView context = findViewById(R.id.id_context);
context.setText((CharSequence) username);
// System.out.println(username);
```

But If I run this code, after the app starts I see "App has been stopped". What is wrong with my code?

Of course, I give permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace

Comment: Try to add runtime permission, may be that work.

Comment: GET_ACCOUNTS is a runtime permission

Comment: @Ashish Executing https://textuploader.com/16oxm

Comment: @Neck Yes i get to permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> Something else? App still stop...

Comment: @david751 I was mentioning "Runtime Permissions", they are not the Manifest permissions. They are written inside your java class. Search on google for Runtime permissions in Android.